# List output at the end of loop

Tags: c, loops

This C program has the user enter 10 expressions and the program will return an answer. The output will look something like this:

Type in your expression: 1+2

3

Type in your expression: 1/2

0.5

etc etc

My question is how do I print the output at the end of the loop instead of one at a time. So it will look more like this:

Type in your expression: 1+2

Type in your expression: 1/2

3

0.5

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float value1, value2;
    char operator;
    int i;
    
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
        
        printf("Type in your expression. \n");
        scanf ("%f %c %f",&value1,&operator,&value2);
        switch(operator)
        {
            case '+':
                printf("%.2f \n", value1 + value2);
                break;
            case '-':
                printf("%.2f \n", value1 - value2);
                break;
            case '*':
                printf("%.2f \n", value1 * value2);
                break;
            case '/':
                printf("%.2f \n", value1 / value2);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Unknown Operator \n");
                break;
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have to store the values, perhaps using an array.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, you need to store the results in an array

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
      float value1 = 0, value2 = 0;
      char operator = 0;
      
      // array where we will store the results
      float results[10] = {0};
      
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
 
      printf("Type in your expression. \n");
      scanf ("%f %c %f",&value1,&operator,&value2);
      switch(operator) 
      {
        case '+':
          results[i] = value1 + value2;
          break;
        case '-':
          results[i] = value1 - value2;
          break;
        case '*':
          results[i] = value1 * value2;
          break;
        case '/':
          results[i] = value1 / value2;
          break;
        default:
          printf("Unknown Operator \n"); 
          return 0;
        }
     }
     // print the results in the array
     for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
          printf("Result of %d is : %.2f", i, results[i]);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use an array of structs, to store the operation, and values then print them at the end.

Also your initial loop should be `i = 0; i < 10;` rather than `i=1; i<=10;`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct MOperation{
    float value1;
    float value2;
    char op;
    float result;
};
int main()
{
    int i;
    struct MOperation operations[10] = {0};
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        struct MOperation temp = {0};
        printf("Type in your expression. \n");
        scanf ("%f %c %f",&temp.value1,&temp.op,&temp.value2);
        switch(temp.op){
            case '+':
                temp.result = temp.value1 + temp.value2;
                break;
            case '-':
                temp.result = temp.value1 - temp.value2;
                break;
            case '*':
                temp.result = temp.value1 * temp.value2;
                break;
            case '/':
                temp.result = temp.value1 / temp.value2;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Unknown Operator \n");
                break;
        }
        memcpy(&operations[i],&temp,sizeof(struct MOperation));
    }
    for(i = 0; i<10; ++i){
        printf("operation %.2f %c %.2f = %.2f\n",operations[i].value1,
               operations[i].op,
               operations[i].value2,
               operations[i].result);
    }
    return 0;
}
```